# Can a constant be added to the inside of an integral without changing its value?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've just come across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8uZYdd4Jnk) that shows a trick to solve some integrals a lot easier and quicker than normal. (allegedly the guy found this trick in **Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus** by Kenneth A. Ross, though I haven't checked).

I'll use $\int x*tan^{-1}(x)dx$ as an example.

In the video, he says that "adding a constant to the anti-derivative of a function doesn't change it; it's still a valid antiderivative" and then he solves it using integration by parts:

$\int x*tan^{-1}(x)dx=\frac{x^2}{2}*tan^{-1}(x)-\int\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

But here instead of proceeding as usual, he replaces $x^2$ with $x^2+1$, making it:

$\int x*tan^{-1}(x)dx=\frac{x^2+1}{2}*tan^{-1}(x)-\int\frac{x^2+1}{2}\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

So the $x^2+1$ in the $\int vdu$ part cancel nicely and we're left with $\int \frac{1}{2}dx$, which is of course very easy to solve. I solved the integral using the "conventional" way and his solution matches the correct solution; and this I don't understand. How does adding 1 not change the integral? The trick changes the $uv$ part from $\frac{x^2}{2}*tan^{-1}(x)$ to $\frac{x^2}{2}*tan^{-1}(x) + tan^{-1}(x)$, which definitely isn't *just* the addition of a constant.

Can someone please explain how this trick is possible?

Comment: he's not even using what you said. He just added and subtracted $\frac 12tan^{-1}(x) = \frac 12\int \frac 1{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to integrate by parts, you look at the integral in the form

$$\int u v'\mathrm dx$$

In the example given, $u = \tan^{-1}(x)$ and $v'=x$. All he's saying is that you can choose *any* antiderivative of $v'$ you want. One antiderivative is $\tfrac12 x^2$. But one that works better with the algebra is $\tfrac12 (x^2+1)$.